# Why custom objects must be Serialized before they can be send between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization, marshalling, parcelable

In Android if app wants to send the custom object from one `Activity` to another, using `Intent`, it can implement 1.`Serializable` interface or 2. `Parcelable`

I understand the difference between these two, and also know that `Parcelable` is preferred choice(for performance reason) and also aware of how to use/code these.

My **question** is: Why `Intent` does not have this support "out-of-the-box"?
As we know, Intent allows to pass primitives directly.

What technical challenges are there that in Android, custom objects **must be** Serialized before they can be send between activities using `Intent`? The same is true for activities within the same process.

Is this Limitation from Virtual Machine side?

Comment: The concept of Intents is supposed to be process-agnostic, so it is built on interprocess communication and has the limitations thereof.  Even if the sender and receiver are in the same process, the intermediary system code is not

Comment: I think this question pretty much covers the reason behind this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940290/the-rationale-behind-android-intent-system